# I want my <nav> to be 100% of document's heigth but css % doesn't work

Tags: html, css, height, width, nav

My style for nav ...

```
nav.menu-desktop{
width: 15%;
height: 100%;
background-color: #b54e74;
margin-top: 4px;
margin-left: 4px;
margin-right: 8px;
margin-bottom: 8px;
font-size: 24px;
color: whitesmoke;
float: left;
display: box;}
```

doesn't work on my html site:

```
<nav id ="menu-desktop">
<div align="left" >
<p align="center" >Menu</p>
<ul>
    <li><a href="kontakt.html">Kontakt</a></li>
    <li><a href="moje_konto.html">Moje konto</a></li>
    <li><a href="OVenidi.html">O Venidi</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</nav>
```

I tried getting rid of the div but it did nothing.
Other styles work just fine and I have no idea why this one doesn't.
[Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVcjT.png)

Comment: 100% of what? Unless you have something like `body { min-height: 100vh }`, your `<nav>` will only be as high as the total height of its content elements when the parent of `<nav>` has no specific height.

Answer (score 0):

Nav element have id, your seletor is class selector. Change `nav.menu-desktop` to
`nav#menu-desktop`

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems in your code:

1. `nav.menu-desktop`: you're calling an id with a class name. Fix it to `nav#menu-desktop`
2. There's no closing tag for nav tag in the HTML you provided.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the display Box, I would recommend you to use flex. As flex works across all devices it can easily solve your problem.

You can refer to this link for better understanding of flex

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

try using "100vh" not "100%" ('vh' is the device height)